# How can I check if an anonymous function has a property?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, anonymous-function

I've coded a JavaScript with an anonymous function and has a property:

```js
!function(e) {
    for(;e.length;){
        e.shift()();
        console.log(e[0].hasOwnProperty('a');
    }
}

([(function(){
    this.a = function(){
        console.log("hello");
    }
}),
function(){
    //no property here
}]);
```

I got an Error when i print `e[0].hasOwnProperty('a')` to the console

It says::::Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

I want to read and check if that anonymous function in array parameter has property.

Comment: the issue is that once you `e.shift()` the SECOND time, `e[0]` is undefined - you're also skipping the first function in the `console.log(e.....)` which is why you don't see it output

Comment: the other issue is, none of those functions will ever have a property `a` anyway

Comment: so how do i add property in the anonymous function?

Comment: when defining them ... you can't (not quite true, you could do an IIFE)... but in your code, `e[0].a = "propertyValue"`

Comment: IIFE ... creating the function with a property ... i.e the first one in your array ... `(() => {
        const fn = function() { }; fn.a = function(){ console.log("hello"); }; return fn; })()`

Comment: thanks a lot I forgot to invoke the anonymous function and ```return this;```

Comment: That won't help the other issues with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are testing `e[0]` after you have shifted the first value out, therefore on the last iteration, you'll be checking `undefined` since for an empty array `e[0] === undefined`

Secondly, `this.a = value` does NOT add a property to a function - unless that function is used like `new fn()` - then the resulting object WILL have a property called `a`

you could

```js
! function(e) {
  for (; e.length;) {
    const fn = e.shift();
    var o = new fn();
    console.log(o.hasOwnProperty('a'));
  }
}([function() {
    this.a = function() {
      console.log("hello");
    };
  },
  function() {
    //no property here
  }
]);
```

Alternatively, you could define that first function like

```
(() => {
  const fn = function() { }; 
  fn.a = function(){ 
    console.log("hello"); 
  }; 
  return fn; 
})()
```

Which would make your code

```js
! function(e) {
  for (; e.length;) {
    const fn = e.shift();
    //fn(); // you don't actually need to run it
    console.log(fn.hasOwnProperty('a'));
  }
}([(() => {
    const fn = function() {};
    fn.a = function() {
      console.log("hello");
    };
    return fn;
  })(),
  function() {
    //no property here
  }
]);
```